Explain intuitively the bases for the tangent and cotangent spaces for a Euclidean space
Suppose we are working in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Suppose I choose some point $p$. The tangent space would be $T_p\mathbb{R}^2$ and cotangent space denoted $T^*_p\mathbb{R}^2$.
I learned today that

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ is a basis for the tangent space
$dx,dy$ is a basis for the cotangent space

I'm just confused what these bases means intuitively.
When I think of vector spaces, I usually think of maps, like Google maps. So in 2D, if I have a vector $(3,5)$ I imagine walking 3m East and 5m North.
So I'm having a lot of difficulty imagining how to walk in a space built of out vectors like $dx,dy$ or $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, even if I feel comfortable using those vectors in certain contexts (e.g. Differentiation with linear operators).
How do the basis vectors  $\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ and $dx,dy$  relate to the more familiar concept of vectors like $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ ? What does it mean to "walk" along these vectors in the context of the tangent space and cotangent space? how do I recover intuitive notions of what these concepts mean?

It might be helpful to separate the notions of the basis of a tangent space at a single point, $T_p$, and how to think about "walking" in a direction. The second topic involves tangent spaces at multiple points and how those change along the manifold. If the manifold is $\mathbb{R}^2$ then the tangent planes are all basically the same, but it is more complicated in the more general case. For the first point, here is a good answer

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}$ It's almost easier to explain this for an abstract manifold $M$.
First, recall that $T_pM$ can be viewed as the space of all possible velocity vectors of curves passing through $p$. In particular, given any smooth parameterized curve through $p$, its velocity at $p$ is an element of $T_pM$. Conversely, given any element in $T_pM$, there is a parameterized curve through $p$ whose velocity at $p$ is the given element.
Recall that a coordinate chart (or its inverse) is a smooth map $\Phi: O \rightarrow M$, where $O \subset \R^n$ is open. Denote the coordinates on $O$ by $(x,y)$. Given any $p \in \Phi(O)$, let
$$ \Phi(x_0,y_0) = p. $$
Consider the curves obtained by holding one coordinate fixed and using the other as a parameter:
\begin{align*}
c_1(t) &= \Phi(t,y_0)\\
c_2(t) &= \Phi(x_0,t).
\end{align*}
Observe that $c_1(x_0) = c_2(y_0) = p$. The definition of the coordinate vector fields at $p$ are
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} &= c_1'(x_0)\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} &= c_2'(y_0)
\end{align*}
Next, recall that given a smooth scalar function $f: M \rightarrow \R$, its differential at $p\in M$ is an element of the cotangent space at $p$,
$$
df(p) \in T^*_pM.
$$
Each coordinate defines a scalar function
\begin{align*} x: \Phi(O) &\rightarrow \R\\
y: \Phi(O) &\rightarrow \R
\end{align*}
Therefore, for each $p \in \Phi(O)$, $dx(p), dy(p) \in T_p^*M$.
It can be checked that the definition of coordinate charts imply that
$$ \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right) $$
is a basis of $T_pM$ and $(dx,dy)$ is a basis of $T_p^*M$. The miracle is that one is the dual basis to the other.
You now can set $O = M = \R^2$ and let $\Phi: \R^2 \rightarrow \R^2$ be the identity map. If you do that, then
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} &= (1,0)\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} &= (0,1).
\end{align*}
Also, $dx$ is the differential of the function
\begin{align*}
x: \R^2 &\rightarrow \R\\
(a,b) &\mapsto a
\end{align*}
and $dy$ is the differential of the function
\begin{align*}
y: \R^2 &\rightarrow \R\\
(a,b) &\mapsto b.
\end{align*}

If I understand correctly, on a smooth manifold, the points on the manifold reside in neighborhoods diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. But why can the tangent vectors live in a vector space if the original points cannot? What allows us to create a vector space from the derivatives of the curve but not vectors for points or on points for the curve itself?

I like this question better than your original one. There's not enough room to answer it in a comment, and I prefer not to make my answer any longer. Perhaps you could post this as a separate question on this site? If I see it, I'll provide an answer. I'm also pretty sure others will answer it, too.

Absolutely! And thanks for taking the time to answer these. I've been trying a while to learn this and finally getting somewhere!

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4976227/why-does-a-manifold-have-a-vector-space-for-its-tangent-vectors-but-not-the-ori
