Why does a manifold have a vector space for its tangent vectors but not the original points on the manifold?
If I understand correctly, on a smooth manifold, the points on the manifold reside in neighborhoods diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$
But why can the tangent vectors live in a vector space if the original points cannot? What allows us to create a vector space from the derivatives of the curve but not vectors for points or on points for the curve itself?
EDIT:
Consider $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let's suppose I am considering a particle's position $\mathbf{x}(t)$ as a function of time such that I'm tracking its position over time. The velocity is
$$\mathbf{v}(t) = \frac{d \mathbf{x}(t)}{dt}$$
This works is because, we can define the position and therefore the displacement vector $\mathbf{x}(t+\epsilon) - \mathbf{x}(t)$ is defined, so consequently so is the derivative. Vectors work here because Euclidean geodesics are straight.
But let's suppose we are on a sphere.
Well, the position $\mathbf{x}(t)$ is not definable as a vector now because, wherever the origin of the coordinate system is, we can no longer draw a vector between those two points since geodesics are no longer straight lines but now curves.
Note, that's not to say we couldn't put the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and then use a vector in the ambient space to define it. What we are saying is that, if we wish to use the surface itself for an "intrinsic" definition, then can't use vectors.
And so therefore, if $\mathbf{x}(t)$ is not defined in terms of vectors, the difference in positions is also not definable with vectors $\mathbf{x}(t+\epsilon) - \mathbf{x}(t)$.
To recover a notion of position on the sphere, we will instead define a curve.
Instead of using a vector field to define the particle’s position $\mathbf{x}(t)$ (which makes sense in Euclidean space but not intrinsically on a curved surface like a sphere), we will define a curve on the sphere. A curve on a manifold (in this case, the sphere $S^2$) is a smooth mapping:
$$
\gamma: I \to S^2
$$
where $I$ is some interval of time (say, $I = [t_0, t_1]$), and $\gamma(t)$ represents the position of the particle on the sphere at time $t$. Specifically, at each time $t$, the particle is located at the point $\gamma(t)$ on the surface of the sphere.
For example, if we describe the sphere $S^2$ using spherical coordinates $(\theta, \phi)$, where $\theta$ is the azimuthal angle (longitude) and $\phi$ is the polar angle (colatitude), the curve $\gamma(t)$ could be written as:
$$
\gamma(t) = (\theta(t), \phi(t))
$$
This $\gamma(t)$ would represent a smooth trajectory on the surface of the sphere, where at each instant $t$, the particle is located at the corresponding $(\theta(t), \phi(t))$ on the sphere.
So given that $\gamma$ is not a vector, there's no reason why the derivative of this curve should be a vector. And I thought that derivative was the tangent vector. So I'm confused why this should be a vector given all the comments above.

I think you are perhaps confusing two issues. The tangent vectors at a fixed point form a vector space (surely, you can add and scale such vectors). But once the point starts varying, you cannot relate the vector space at one point to the vector space at another.

@TedShifrin I added some comments that may help clarify my point of confusion. If you get a chance to reread, that would be awesome.

It's hard to engage in a week-long lecture in this setting. You can work in a chart — in local coordinates — and do whatever algebra and calculus you want with vectors in that open subset of Euclidean space. The point is that tangent vectors to curves will be well-defined, independent of your choice of chart, whereas your other constructions (e.g., the difference between two points, let alone the sum) will not be. The tangent space at a point, however you define it, is a vector space that is independent of any chart you might be working in.

You are looking for the distinction between a point and a vector.

A smooth manifold is indeed a space that locally resembles Euclidean space, but this does not mean that the manifold itself is a vector space. Here's why tangent vectors can be considered as elements of a vector space, while the points of the manifold are not:
Local Structure: At each point on a smooth manifold, there exists a neighborhood that is diffeomorphic to an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. This means that around each point, the manifold looks like flat space, but this is only locally true, not globally.
Tangent Spaces: The tangent space at a point on a manifold is the vector space that consists of all tangent vectors to the manifold at that point. A tangent vector can be thought of as an infinitesimal displacement or a directional derivative of a curve on the manifold at that point. The tangent space at each point is independent of the global structure of the manifold.
The tangent vectors live in a vector space because they represent the possible directions of motion and rates of change at a point on the manifold, which is a purely local concept. The points of the manifold, on the other hand, do not live in a vector space because the manifold's global structure does not allow for vector space operations in a way that is consistent with its topology and geometry.

Is the tangent space part of the manifold? That was also something I was unclear about.

The tangent space is not part of the manifold. It is an algebraic object attached to each point of the manifold. You can consider the set of all pairs $(x,v)$ such that $x\in M$ and $v\in T_xM$, known as the tangent bundle (which is itself a manifold). This manifold in a way considers all of the tangents at all points and gives us a more global view of the relation between $M$ and its collection of tangent spaces, whereas just fixing $x\in M$ and looking at the tangent space $T_xM$ amounts to a local view which is just studying a vector space

@whpowell96 and an affine connection on the tangent bundle then allows us to compare vectors between tangent spaces?
